# Control AppleTV with terminal or web?

Tags: appletv

Is there any way to control an Apple TV 1st gen either through terminal connection or a web interface (ideally using a REST interface)?

By "control" I mean don't mean "control everything".  One example use-case would be: Give the ATV a MP3 stream URL and have it play.

If some kind of "hacking" or plugin is involved, that's ok!

Comment: I think you need to be a little more clear about what your goals are in doing this. It'd be great to know exactly what you want to accomplish and why so we can provide the best answer possible. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'm just asking, is it possible to hack any kind of "scripting interface" or "API" onto the ATV, which could be accessed via web or terminal?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such interface available for the default ATV2 shell, however you could install [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) (jailbreaking required) and use [XBMC API](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Archive%3aWeb_Server_HTTP_API) to control it.

If you really want to control the default interface (now called AppleTV.app), you have two possible routes (both beyond the scope of this site and question):

- Reverse engineer the protocol used in the remote app.
- Reverse engineer the AppleTV.app and use some way (mobilesubstrate) to inject hooks for functions or whole network interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you jailbreak your Apple TV, you can [SSH into it](http://www.ultrasn0w.ca/2011/04/how-to-ssh-into-your-jailbroken-apple.html). I'm not sure what the functionality would be, but it can be done. You would then use [these](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2009/06/ssh-into-your-mac.html) steps to access it remotely.

Does that answer your question?